Sending .lmf file to Bluetooth printer
I'm trying to work out how to print labels on a Bluetooth printer from a React app. Apparently I need to 'build' a .lmf file to send to the printer once paired with the device. I can build the file with all the data to be printed onto the label, but I have no idea as how to send this file from the React front-end to the printer on an android device or iPhone/iPad.
If anyone has any experience in this area, I'd be very grateful for any pointers. I've searched everywhere for an answer, but have come up empty handed. Thanks very much in advance if you can help
I haven't been able to try anything as yet as I can't find any useful information on the subject

Is it published as a specification somewhere? For example, if you search, you will find sites and articles like this. Opening LabelMark Files from Previous Versions in LabelMark 6, LabelMark 3 User Guide According to that, it seems to be a very old proprietary product, but is that what you're talking about? If not, you may want to add information or documentation about the .lmf files you have.
